# Why does form not reset (all fields and div of result) after click clear?

Tags: javascript, html

I want display div `id="showResult"` after click calculate button and clear all input and div `id="showResult"` after click clear button in a form. But clear button doesn't work after I click the button.

What's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

```js
window.onload = function BMR() {
  var gender = document.getElementById('gender');
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight');
  var height = document.getElementById('height');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');
  calculate.addEventListener('click', toBmr);

  function toBmr() {
    var select = null;

    if (gender.value && weight.value && height.value && age.value) {
      if (document.getElementById('gender').checked) {
        select = document.getElementById('gender').value;
      }

      if (select == 'male') {
        var result = (10 * weight.value) + (6.25 * height.value) - (5 * age.value) + 5;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Number(result).toFixed(2);
      } else {
        var result = (10 * weight.value) + (6.25 * height.value) - (5 * age.value) - 161;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Number(result).toFixed(2);
      }
      document.getElementById('showResult').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      result = " ";
    }
  };
};

function clearForm() {
  document.getElementById("do-form").reset();
}
```

```html
<form name="do-form" id="do-form">
  <p>BMR Calculator</p>
  <p>Gender:
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" checked="checked">Male
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female
  </p>
  <p>Weight:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 5) return false;">&nbsp;kg</p>
  <p>Height:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="height" id="height" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 5) return false;">&nbsp;cm</p>
  <p>Age:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="age" id="age" size="10" maxlength="3" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 2) return false;"></p>
  <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearForm()">Clear</button><br><br>
  <div class="row-result-tab" id="showResult" style="display:none;">
    <label>BMR = &nbsp;<span id="result"></span>&nbsp;calories/day</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you expect `result = " ";` to do that (clear/remove the div), you're mistaken. You need to either hide the div by setting `result.style.display = "none";` or clear its text using `result.textContent = "";`

Comment: just add `document.getElementById('showResult').style.display = "none"` to the button code

Comment: Also note that you should add `var result = document.getElementById('result');` to the start, like with the other elements. For consistency, and so you're not using it out of scope in the else-block, which falls back to the element because it has that exact `id`.

Comment: Resetting a form only clears the input elements and textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to hide the div in the clearForm

Here  is your code cleaned up based on the DRY principle (don't repeat yourself)

We could get rid of some testing if we could trust the browser to respect the `type="number"` which is fairly well supported

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', toBmr);
});

const toBmr = () => {
  const gender = document.querySelector('[name=gender]:checked').value;
  // the "number" fields will not allow other data than numbers
  let weight = +document.getElementById('weight').value;
  let height = +document.getElementById('height').value;
  let age    = +document.getElementById('age').value;
  if (weight && age && height) {
    let result = (10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age)
    result += gender === 'male' ? 5 : -161; // add 5 for male, subtract 161 if female
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('showResult').style.display = "block";
  }
};

const clearForm = () => {
  document.getElementById("do-form").reset();
  document.getElementById('showResult').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form name="do-form" id="do-form">
  <p>BMR Calculator</p>
  <p>Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="checked">Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  </p>
  <p>Weight:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 5) return false;">&nbsp;kg</p>
  <p>Height:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="height" id="height" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 5) return false;">&nbsp;cm</p>
  <p>Age:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="age" id="age" size="10" maxlength="3" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 2) return false;"></p>
  <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearForm()">Clear</button><br><br>
  <div class="row-result-tab" id="showResult" style="display:none;">
    <label>BMR = &nbsp;<span id="result"></span>&nbsp;calories/day</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That is the -161

Comment: According to my post, I want the result display when get all input in a form only. Otherwise, the result does not display.

Comment: @Patt.M Fixed that too

Comment: I shortened it by not testing for empty but casting to number using `+` immediately

Answer (score 1):

The result div can not auto hide, you need add code to hide it

```
 document.getElementById('showResult').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

or

```
document.getElementById('showResult').style.display= "none";
```

```js
window.onload = function BMR() {
  var gender = document.getElementById('gender');
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight');
  var height = document.getElementById('height');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');
  calculate.addEventListener('click', toBmr);

  function toBmr() {
    var select = null;

    if (gender.value && weight.value && height.value && age.value) {
      if (document.getElementById('gender').checked) {
        select = document.getElementById('gender').value;
      }

      if (select == 'male') {
        var result = (10 * weight.value) + (6.25 * height.value) - (5 * age.value) + 5;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Number(result).toFixed(2);
      } else {
        var result = (10 * weight.value) + (6.25 * height.value) - (5 * age.value) - 161;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Number(result).toFixed(2);
      }
      document.getElementById('showResult').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      result = " ";
    }
  };
};

function clearForm() {
  document.getElementById("do-form").reset();
  //document.getElementById('showResult').style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById('showResult').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form name="do-form" id="do-form">
  <p>BMR Calculator</p>
  <p>Gender:
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" checked="checked">Male
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female
  </p>
  <p>Weight:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 5) return false;">&nbsp;kg</p>
  <p>Height:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="height" id="height" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 5) return false;">&nbsp;cm</p>
  <p>Age:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="age" id="age" size="10" maxlength="3" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 2) return false;"></p>
  <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearForm()">Clear</button><br><br>
  <div class="row-result-tab" id="showResult" style="display:none;">
    <label>BMR = &nbsp;<span id="result"></span>&nbsp;calories/day</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: visibility:hidden keeps the space it takes in the DOM

Comment: Your change was already in my comment 5 min before your answer. There are more stuff to Improve - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I took some time to improve your code. As given in other answers already. You need to set the display of your result html back to none.

```js
window.onload = function BMR() {
  // Init
  var gender = document.getElementById('gender');
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight');
  var height = document.getElementById('height');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');
  
  // Click handler
  calculate.addEventListener('click', toBmr);

  function toBmr() {
    // Init
    // Very good practice to first declare your vars
    // However include result as well here
    // Remove select because it's not doing anything
    var result = "";
    var penalty = 0;
    
    if (gender.value && weight.value && height.value && age.value && gender.checked) {
    // When you have duplicate code, check the difference!
    // Only the penalty given at the end is different!
      if (gender.value == 'male') {
        penalty = 5;
        } else {
        penalty = -161;
        }
        // Now we calculate with one formula
        result = (10 * weight.value) + (6.25 * height.value) - (5 * age.value) + penalty;
        
        // Add to html
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =      Number(result).toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('showResult').style.display = "block";
      }
  };
};

function clearForm() {
  // This resets the form fields
  document.getElementById("do-form").reset();
  
  // This remove result again
  document.getElementById('showResult').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form name="do-form" id="do-form">
  <p>BMR Calculator</p>
  <p>Gender:
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" checked="checked">Male
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female
  </p>
  <p>Weight:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 5) return false;">&nbsp;kg</p>
  <p>Height:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="height" id="height" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 5) return false;">&nbsp;cm</p>
  <p>Age:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="age" id="age" size="10" maxlength="3" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 2) return false;"></p>
  <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearForm()">Clear</button><br><br>
  <div class="row-result-tab" id="showResult" style="display:none;">
    <label>BMR = &nbsp;<span id="result"></span>&nbsp;calories/day</label>
  </div>
</form>
```